# Calling Models function in Controller in Pimcore

Tags: php, function, model-view-controller, pimcore

**Example of controller file which have a function**

use Api\Controller\Action;

```
class Api_WebserviceController extends Zend_Rest_Controller {
  function xyz(){
    echo "xyz";
   }
}
```

**Example of model file in which i have a function .**

```
Class api_model{
function abc_model(){
    $name="model function called in controller";
}
}
```

I want call the model function inside controller function to echo value of $name.

Can anyone suggest me how i can call the **model function in controller** in **Pimcore**.

Answer (score 1):

Put your model files in `/website/lib/` directory and register your "api" namespace in autoloader via `/website/var/config/startup.php`

```php
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()->registerNamespace([
    'api',
]);
```

Then you should be able to use your model everywhere.

```
$model = new api_model();
$model->abc_model();
```

Note: You should follow [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) (or [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md)) specification to allow autoloader to resolve your classes.

Comment: i added file in website model folder .And i am able to call it .Then it is right approach i am doing?????????

For calling model.And it would work in API

Comment: It's correct approach to call your model in API controller.

Comment: Hello Thank you for your help
@rafal Galka

I am calling the model function in my api controller but when i try to echo something in model or it self call model function then i receive a blank page with no error and no output 

Can you have idea about this????????

Comment: It looks like fatal error, enable php errors by ```error_reporting(E_ALL)``` and ```ini_set('display_errors', 1)```. You should see then what is wrong.

Comment: If i want to update the existing user information for example using coding and databse

userinfo :-

Fullname:- Pawan Nagar

i want to update to "Pawan Singh NAgar ksldjaskld"